# How to exclude certain parameters in dynamic urls?

Tags: python, django, django-urls

I am mapping a dynamic url parameter such as a pagename in my application like so myapp.com/[pagenamehere]
My urls.py for this looks like:

```
url(r'^(?P<pagename>[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]*)/$', 
    views.all_pagenames, 
    name='all_pagenames')
```

However, the urls for myapp.com/login, myapp.com/register, myapp.com/about etc are already mapped in the urls.py file like so, for example:

```
url(r'^about/$', views.about, name='about')
```

How can I revise the dynamic url for pagenames so that words such as ‘login’ ‘about’ etc are excluded from possible pagename parameters and don’t forward to the “all_pagenames” function in the views and instead goes to the appropriate function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Django will try each url pattern in definition order, so you don't have to worry about "exluding" your other urls, all you need is to make sure you define them *before* the catch-all "pagename" url pattern:

```
url(r'^about/$', views.about, name='about')
url(r'^login/$', views.login, name='login')
# etc
# and last:
url(r'^(?P<pagename>[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]*)/$', 
     views.all_pagenames, name='all_pagenames')
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am embarrassed it was so simple, and I didn't realize this by reading the documentation. I appreciate the time you took to explain this.

Comment: @SwAvGuy: "Django runs through each URL pattern, in order, and stops at the first one that matches the requested URL." (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/http/urls/#how-django-processes-a-request) ;)